# How to create Linked Server in Sybase IQ DB to connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

We are trying to load data in a table in Sybase IQ from MS SQL Server. We are trying to load it by writing a stored procedure which does insert into ....

Currently, it is unsuccessful as the stored procedure is not able to find the source table directly.

Is it possible to create linked server kind of thing in Sybase IQ to connect to MS SQL source database so that it behaves like a local table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ECDA (used to be called Direct Connect) - there's an explanation of how to set it up here using ECDA on a separate Windows host (easier because then you can use a standard ODBC driver to connect to MSSQL).

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/11/18/connect-sybase-iq-16-on-aix-with-remote-server-to-mssql-with-ecda-without-odbc-configuration/